# How does Swift expect dates to be written?

Tags: swift, nsdate

After `import Foundation`, I wrote a class called ‘Employee’. One of its properties is of type `Date`. My questions is: *when instantiating Employee, how do I format its `Date` property value?* (I've tried YYYY-MM-DD, MM-DD-YYYY, and a few others, but Xcode won’t accept.)

Here's the class:

```
class Employee {
let name: String
let address: String
let startDate: Date
let type: EmployeeType  

init(name: String, address: String, startDate: Date, type: EmployeeType) {
    self.name = name
    self.address = address
    self.startDate = startDate
    self.type = type
}
```

And here's an attempt to create an instance (2017-10-19 isn't accepted):

`let nick = Employee(name: "Nick", address: "61", startDate: 2017-10-19, type: EmployeeType.traditional)`

Many thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a date/time literal syntax, Swift doesn't have one! The shortest method I've found is by constructing a `DateComponents`:

```
let date = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2017, month: 10, day: 19).date!
```

Another thing that I see all too common here on StackOverflow: beware the timezone. If you `print(date)` and don't get back the date/time you asked for, think about converting your requested time in GMT as that what's `Date` always uses